# Resize UIPageViewController with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to change UIPageViewController's width with animation, but the width of page (view of ViewController inside UIPageViewController) is not animating. Setting width of page manually inside animation doesn't help.

White rect inside red stroke is UIPageViewController's background color (its width is decreasing and width of page is already set to final value)

[image]

I noticed that between UIPageVC and my pages there are two views:

```
 UIPageVC.view -> UIQueuingScrollView -> UIView for each page -> pageview itself
```

that are resizing each other. I had no luck trying to set their width or trying to disable autoresizing.
May be someone has encountered a similar situation? Or any ideas, suggests?
Thanks for any help